# start f3 (fat free framework) using composer

Tags: php, composer-php, fat-free-framework

I started my php server from my Downloads folder and I downloaded f3 framework using composer package .
I started the server using the following command and it works

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
```

This is my index.php file

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$f3 = \Base::instance();

function() {
        echo 'Hello, world!';
    }

$f3->set('DEBUG', 1);
$f3->run();
```

My project is in the folder named f3_project .But when I navigate to 
"http://localhost:8000/f3_project/index.php".Its not showing the output .

It says `" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"`.

followed the steps properly to install composer.How should I solve this ? What is the issue?

"In the server this is the error I am getting
/f3_project/index.php - syntax error, unexpected '$f3' (T_VARIABLE)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it may be not obvious, PHP is choking on the illegal definition of your anonymous function ("Hello world").

Obviously you meant to route a URI to this function. The correct syntax is:

```
$f3->route('GET /',function(){
  echo 'Hello world!';
});
```